# Grails Date Contraints

Tags: grails, groovy, constraints

Im trying to add constraints to a user submitted text field, which is there Date of Birth. I need the user to be at least 18 but cant be over 113 years old.

```
final static Date MIN_DATE = new Date(Calendar.YEAR-18)
final static Date MAX_DATE = new Date(Calendar.YEAR-100)

static constraints = {
    dob(nullabe: false, min: MIN_DATE, max: MAX_DATE
}
```

When I,

```
System.out.println('Year Max Date: ' + person.MAX_DATE)
```

it gives me,

```
Year Max Date: Wed Dec 31 17:59:59 CST 1969
```

and so does the min date.

I tried doing

```
final static Date MIN_DATE = new Date().getAt(Calendar.YEAR)-18
```

but that didn't work at all. I also tried doing it without the `-18` and got the correct answer but it was 7 hours off. When I tried to relaunch the app from local it crashed it. And I cant recreate it ever since.

I have come to the understanding that the date its giving is the "Epoch" date or the date right before Unix was launched. Im just not sure how to get around it.

Any ideas/suggestions/concerns/experience with this problem?
Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't agree with these constraints, firstly as they seem arbitrary (why should someone not be older than 100?  And why can't I just lie if I am 16?)

And secondly, if the webserver is up for a couple of years, these static dates will slowly drift

But anyway (these concerns aside), I believe what you want is:

```
final static Date MIN_DATE = Calendar.instance.with { add( YEAR, -18 ) ; it }.time
final static Date MAX_DATE = Calendar.instance.with { add( YEAR, -100 ) ; it }.time
```

Comment: Its a app that employees use. It is just there to catch and avoid typos. But this worked out fine. Thanks a lot. And actually logically, the min and max needed to be switched. I really appreciate that help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `Date` constructor expects an argument representing milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. Since `Calendar.YEAR` is a constant that is used to represent the year field from a `Calendar` structure and equal to 1 you are getting the above values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the user submitted text field (a String) to a Date object with SimpleDateFormat. Then create a Calendar with the Date object and check the Year field.

Alternatively you can just parse the text field (String) yourself and pick the year, convert to int and do the check.